# Is android support IGMP url to play video

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-videoview, android-video-player

Hi i have live streaming video URL which is IGMP protocol, i want to play that live streaming in android device . I have tried with exo-player it has data sources for RTMP and ftp  but there is no IGMP.

1. Is it possible to stream multicast video to android phone using IGMP URL?
2. If yes is there way to do using exo-player
3. No suggest any player support such streaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes we can play IGMP
2. Exo player is not support IGMP or UDP so officially we don't have support

   refer :https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5046
3. We can play that with some changes in exo-player but quality of video is too low

   refer :https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2630
4. VLC able to play the IGMP data